# NestJS - Mongoose @InjectConnection unit testing

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, gridfs, nestjs

I have a service that uses the `@InjectConnection` decorator in it's constructor.

I am unable to instantiate a testingModule for this service. The following error is thrown: `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AttachmentsService (?, winston). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the TestModule context.`

Service constructor:

```
  constructor(@InjectConnection() private readonly mongooseConnection: Mongoose,
              @Inject(Modules.Logger) private readonly logger: Logger) {
    this.attachmentGridFsRepository = gridfs({
      collection: 'attachments',
      model: Schemas.Attachment,
      mongooseConnection: this.mongooseConnection,
    });

    this.attachmentRepository = this.attachmentGridFsRepository.model;
  }
```

Test module constructor:

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
    WinstonModule.forRoot({
      transports: [
        new transports.Console({
          level: 'info',
          handleExceptions: false,
          format: format.combine(format.json()),
        }),
      ],
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AttachmentsService, {
    provide: getConnectionToken(''),
    useValue: {},
  }],
}).compile();

service = module.get<AttachmentsService>(AttachmentsService);
```

I realize that I will have to mock the connection object to be callable by GridFS, but right now I am unable to actually get the test module to build.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you do not add an explicit connection name, nest.js will [use the default connection token](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/blob/42e38d4ad088057bb8f551081a0fb1538e7eb34d/lib/common/mongoose.decorators.ts#L8) `DatabaseConnection`, which is defined as a constant by the nestjs-mongoose package:

```
export const DEFAULT_DB_CONNECTION = 'DatabaseConnection';
```

So you can use `getConnectionToken('Database')`:

```
providers: [AttachmentsService, {
  provide: getConnectionToken('Database'),
  useValue: {},
}]
```

---

### Update 2019

The pull request was merged. You can now `getConnectionToken()`.

I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/pull/30) which lets `getConnectionToken()` without any parameters return the default connection token.